# Sample JSON format to create salesOrder in netsuite using API

Tags: json, netsuite

can someone help me with the JSON format for  (creating)posting salesOrder in netsuite ???Thanks in advance...

```
{
    "entity": {
        "id": {{lastCustomer}}
    },
    "item": {
        "items": [
            {
                "item":
                {
                    "id": "814"
                },
                "rate": 10
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

this is what I have tried...but it says "Error while accessing resource: You have entered an Invalid Field Value 814 for the following field: item". I have tried giving the Id field value as number but no luck.
Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to define the record type.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48297799/netsuite-restlet-inserting-sales-order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working JSON:

```
{
        "recordtype": "salesorder",
        "entity": {
            "id": {{lastCustomer}}
        },
        "item": {
            "items": [
                {
                    "item": {
                        "id": "945"
                    },
                    "rate": 10
                }
            ]
        },
        "location": {
            "id": "2"
        },
        "department": {
            "id": "3"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON format is correct (tested and confirmed in my account). You are getting the error because the item is not valid for the customer.

Comment: I am sorry to ask this but, how do i find which items are available for that customer. I am really new to net suite and I have searching really hard but, could not find the answer. Problem is that I don't have the login credentials for this net suite account to view the UI. Are there any ways to find the items available for a customer ? Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Thank u for your time and effort...{
 "recordtype": "salesorder",
 "entity": {
  "id": {{lastCustomer}}
 },
 "item": {
  "items": [
   {
    "item": {
     "id": "945"
    },
    "rate": 10
   }
  ]
 },
 "location": {
  "id": "2"
 },
 "department": {
  "id": "3"
 }
}